# Spark RichEditableText weirdness when heightInLines="1"

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Try this:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:Panel id="pnl">
        <s:RichEditableText id="richEdTxt"
            width="200"
            maxChars="100" />
    </s:Panel>

</s:Application>
```

Now set heightInLines="1":

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:Panel id="pnl">
        <s:RichEditableText id="richEdTxt"
            width="200"
            maxChars="100"
            heightInLines="1" />
    </s:Panel>

</s:Application>
```

See the problem when you fill up the RichEditableText with characters? Keep typing the word hello until you cross outside of the first visible area of the RichEditableText. things get weird. Try it out. Anyone have any ideas how to prevent the weirdness? (the text starts jumping up and down)

[image: all is well]

[image: crossed over]

[image: text jumps down]

[image: then back up and looks good]

[image: then down and bad again]

Comment: +1 vote for u, I tried this it seems to be work like that as u said

Comment: Which Flex SDK are you using? I've just tried that on Flex 4.5.1 and it seems very stable. The only little thing a noticed is a really very small text jump when you select a lot of text with the mouse. But otherwise it seems very stable. Please provide some more information.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention - sdk 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that appears to have been fixed in a later SDK - but I can't seem to find the JIRA ticket for it.